# Is accessing a variable created using malloc inside a loop faster than a locally declared variable?

Tags: c, performance, variables, malloc, calloc

I have an application that is on a loop and uses a variable. Basically it just copies a string into the variable processes it and then move to the next string. I was wondering how should I declare the variable that I need to use so I wrote this code to test which one would be faster. Its interesting to see that malloc is faster than the variable that I declared locally. I have also thrown in calloc and its slower since its probably zeroing the memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

struct rusage ruse;
#define CPU_TIME (getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF,&ruse), ruse.ru_utime.tv_sec +  ruse.ru_stime.tv_sec + 1e-6 *  (ruse.ru_utime.tv_usec + ruse.ru_stime.tv_usec))

void gen_random_letters(char *random_buffer, const int len)
{
    int i;
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    /* initialize random seed: */
    srand (time(NULL));

    for ( i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        random_buffer[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }

    random_buffer[len] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    clock_t tic;
    clock_t toc;
    int counter;
    char *buffer_calloc;
    char *buffer_malloc;
    char buffer_local_variable[1450];
    char copy_this[1450];
    double time_spent;
    double first, second;
    int loop_max;

    loop_max = 5000000;
    gen_random_letters(copy_this, sizeof(copy_this));

    /* Try the locally declared variable */
    tic  = clock();
    first = CPU_TIME;
    for ( counter = 0; counter <= loop_max; counter++ )
    {
        //memset(buffer_local_variable,0,sizeof(buffer_local_variable));
        memcpy(buffer_local_variable,copy_this,sizeof(buffer_local_variable));
    }
    toc = clock();
    second = CPU_TIME;
    time_spent = (toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("cpu local_variable : %.2f secs\n", second - first);
    printf("Elapsed local_variable: %f seconds\n\n", time_spent);

    /* Try calloc */
    tic  = clock();
    first = CPU_TIME;
    for ( counter = 0; counter <= loop_max; counter++ ){
        buffer_calloc = calloc(1450,sizeof(char*));
        memcpy(buffer_calloc,copy_this,sizeof(buffer_calloc));
        free(buffer_calloc);
    }
    toc = clock();
    second = CPU_TIME;
    time_spent = (toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("cpu calloc  : %.2f secs\n", second - first);
    printf("Elapsed calloc : %f seconds\n\n", time_spent);

    /* And now malloc */
    tic  = clock();
    first = CPU_TIME;
    for ( counter = 0; counter <= loop_max; counter++ ){
        buffer_malloc = malloc(1450 * sizeof(char*));
        memcpy(buffer_malloc,copy_this,sizeof(buffer_malloc));
        free(buffer_malloc);
    }
    toc = clock();
    second = CPU_TIME;
    time_spent = (toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Cpu malloc  : %.2f secs\n", second - first);
    printf("Elapsed malloc : %f seconds\n", time_spent);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
cpu local_variable : 0.57 secs
Elapsed local_variable : 0.000000 seconds

cpu calloc  : 2.08 secs
Elapsed calloc : 2.000000 seconds

Cpu malloc  : 0.39 secs
Elapsed malloc : 0.000000 seconds
```

I was expecting the locally declared variable to be faster since the memory for it is already allocated unlike the malloc where it needs to be called every loop. Is my code flawed that is why malloc is faster or that is just the way it is.

Comment: I assume you've done more than one run per 'version' and this is the average or something, right? And you've tried them in different orders in case it's some caching thing going on? Have to make your you're comparing apples with apples...

Comment: Your output doesn't match the code. When I run this code on my laptop (after removing backslashes from the `CPU_TIME` macro), the winner is "buffer_fixed" which isn't in your output at all.

Comment: The results on my machine are consistent even when reordering the three tests.

Comment: @smarx Sorry its just the text on the printf. I already edited the code.

Comment: In any case, I think the answer so far is "no repro." You may have to narrow things down in terms of compiler, architecture, etc. to see why the machine you tested on has this behavior.

Comment: When you call malloc, it goes in and rummages down a list of memory blocks to find one big enough, peels off the amount you want, readjusts the list, and returns back to you. Then when you free what you previously allocated, it has to do a similar amount of work. That can easily be the dominant cost in a program. Having a local variable can cost basically nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code copies the wrong number of bytes in the `calloc` and `malloc` cases. `sizeof(buffer_malloc)` gives you the size of the pointer.

Try using 1450 instead of `sizeof(...)` for those cases.

Results on my laptop (2015 Macbook) with the above change:

```
cpu local_variable : 0.16 secs
Elapsed local_variable: 0.000000 seconds

cpu calloc  : 1.60 secs
Elapsed calloc : 1.000000 seconds

Cpu malloc  : 0.56 secs
Elapsed malloc : 0.000000 seconds
```

**UPDATE**

You're also allocating `1450 * sizeof(char*)` bytes with `malloc`, when you should really be using `1450 * sizeof(char)`.

After that fix, the results get a little closer:

```
cpu local_variable : 0.16 secs
Elapsed local_variable: 0.000000 seconds

cpu calloc  : 0.76 secs
Elapsed calloc : 0.000000 seconds

Cpu malloc  : 0.57 secs
Elapsed malloc : 0.000000 seconds
```

Comment: Good catch :) My results are close to yours now. So is it safe to assume that the local variable is faster than mallocing on each loop?

Comment: @kuchi As a rule, I try to never write C code, so I have no idea. :-) But the results do seem to suggest that, and it seems intuitively correct.

Comment: @kuchi:  In general, yes; the `malloc` and `calloc` calls add some overhead that using a local array doesn't, so the first version should be faster.  But don't make raw speed your primary criterion for using either method - sometimes, dynamic allocation is the right answer, even if it's slower.